# How can I obtain the last inserted row with INSERT ... SELECT in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, insert, select-into

I'm trying to batch-copy data in a specific order from one table to another in PostgreSQL 12-beta2. The table is *not* using sequences, but contains an composite unique Primary Key (`user_id, object_id`).

In order to determine where to start for the next batch, I'd like to start off from the last inserted row (`WHERE user_id >= last_user_id AND object_id > last_object_id`).

Starting off with this:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT (user_id, object_id, object_type, colN, ...) 
FROM source_table 
ORDER BY user_id, colN, object_id  -- this is indexed
LIMIT 1000  -- batch size
RETURNING user_id, object_id;
```

... returns a table of 1000 tuples. I'd like to obtain the last inserted tuple from it.

I've tried to do a SELECT around it, like this:

```
SELECT user_id, object_id FROM (
    INSERT INTO dest_table
    SELECT (user_id, object_id, object_type, colN, ...) 
    FROM source_table 
    ORDER BY user_id, colN, object_id  -- this is indexed
    LIMIT 1000  -- batch size
    RETURNING user_id, object_id
)
ORDER BY user_id DESC, colN DESC, object_id DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURNING user_id, object_id;
```

But that returns a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 2: INSERT INTO dest_table
               ^
```

I've also attempted `RETURNING ... INTO variable` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id/2944481#comment64237933_2944335), but that fails too:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 23: RETURNING user_id, object_id INTO my_variable;
                                      ^
```

Do I need to create a function for this (e.g. plpgsql) or am I missing something obvious in plain SQL that let me do this? That would be highly favorable.

Comment: Have you considered to add sequence or timestamp column?

Comment: @McNets Yes, but this rebuild concerns a large table that happens concurrently (working around CLUSTER/pg_repack/pg_squeeze limitations), and I would need to ALTER TABLE ADD/DELETE COLUMN on both source and destination tables, which is not considered doable at this point given the data size. Anyway, I think I have a much simpler solution; extra select on destination table during next batch... (how stupid that I have missed that!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need only the maximum of the last inserted (user_id,object_id) as a couple. The first INSERT could be:

```
WITH inserted_rows as (
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT user_id, object_id, object_type, colN, ...
FROM source_table 
ORDER BY user_id, colN, object_id  -- this is indexed
LIMIT 1000  -- batch size
RETURNING user_id, object_id
)
SELECT row(user_id,object_id) FROM inserted_rows
 ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This form uses a row to refer to the `(user_id,object_id)` couple for convenience. Row elements are compared left-to-right as needed in your case to use this couple of values as a boundary. See 
 [Row Constructor Comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) in the documentation.

With this solution, the subsequent INSERTs would inject the value returned by the last preceding insert. This avoids looking up the last inserted row in `dest_table`.

```
WITH inserted_rows as (
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT user_id, object_id, object_type, colN, ...
FROM source_table
  WHERE row(user_id,object_id) > row(...inject the result of the previous query here...)
ORDER BY user_id, colN, object_id
LIMIT 1000
RETURNING user_id, object_id
)
SELECT row(user_id,object_id) FROM inserted_rows
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

> Do I need to create a function for this (e.g. plpgsql) or am I missing
>   something obvious in plain SQL that let me do this? That would be
>   highly favorable.

In plain SQL, you would do a single INSERT in one step without any batching. Since you want to break it into batches, there has to be some loop driving these INSERTs with a stop condition, and this procedural logic goes beyond pure SQL.

If you don't feel like reinjecting the boundary through a variable, it could be persisted in a dedicated, single-row table.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the `max(<row>)` function by the way. Am I doing something wrong? `ERROR:  function max(record) does not exist
LINE xxx: SELECT max(row(user_id,object_id)) FROM inserted_rows;
`. (Also the parentheses around the first SELECT seem not right.)

Comment: @gertvdijk: indeed max() doesn't work on a record, not sure why because greatest() does, but anyway I've replace it by an `order by limit 1`. As for the parentheses in the select, I've removed them but that part of the query was copy-pasted straight from the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If no-one else is writing to `dest_table` except yourself, obtain the last inserted ID in a subquery on all subsequent batches, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT (user_id, object_id, object_type, colN, ...) 
FROM source_table
WHERE
    user_id >= (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM dest_table
        ORDER BY user_id DESC, colN DESC, object_id DESC
        LIMIT 1)
    )
    AND object_id > (
        SELECT event_id
        FROM dest_table
        ORDER BY user_id DESC, colN DESC, object_id DESC
        LIMIT 1)
    )
ORDER BY user_id, colN, object_id
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: This could be a lot more efficient, probably; any hints appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps using [cursors](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/) in PL/pgSQL with FETCH would be the best way to do what I'm doing...